# how to bind the JSON data into dropdown list using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, drop-down-menu

I am getting this result as JSON output. How do I bind this output in my dropdown using jquery ?

This is jquery code:

```
function OnSuccess(response) {  

     var ddlCity = $("[id*=SiteMaster_ddlCity]");
     var ddlState = $("[id*=SiteMaster_ddlState]");
     ddlCity.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
     ddlState.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');                            
     $.each(response.d, function () {
           ddlCity.append($("<option></option>").val(this['CITY']).html(this['CITY']));
                ddlState.append($("<option></option>").val(this['STATE']).html(this['STATE']));
            });

     //  alert(response.d);
}
```

This is the code returning the JSON output

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsCityStatebyZipCode, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: u could use the response value,  $.each function pass the value and index of the enumerated variable; in short u should fill in the params at $.each function () <- in between this parenthesises

Comment: Hi thanks :) It worked

Answer (score 3):

you need to apply the index and value in each loop to get the proper value here is the correct syntax to use it

```
$('.dropdown-content').html('');  //html element where you need to bind the data
    var parseData = jQuery.parseJSON(result.d); // parse the data
    var html = '';            
    $.each(parseData, function (i, v) {   // get data using each loop
        html += "<option>" + v.name+ "</option>";
    });

    $('.dropdown-content').html(html);  // bind the html to targeted element
```

Comment: It is binding as undefined in Dropdownlist :(

Comment: use the debugger and see what is your response

Comment: var parseData = jQuery.parseJSON(response.d); // parse the data+
                var html = '';
                $.each(parseData, function (i, v) {
                    html += "<option>" + v.CITY+ "</option>";                  
                });

Comment: show me your data format in parseData
if there is city in data  then they definitely bind the city
debug it and show me your data format under parseData variable

Comment: parseData = {Table: Array(1)}, response = {d: "{
↵  "Table": [
↵    {
↵      "CITY": "DPO",
↵      "STATE": "Armed Forces America"
↵    }
↵  ]
↵}"}   I am getting parsedata like this in Debugger

Comment: 0
:
CITY
:
"DPO"
STATE
:
"Armed Forces America"
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: i think there is some issue with your data format you are getting from backend use it like this hop it helps
var data = JSON.parse(result.d);
var parseData= parseData.Table;

Comment: $.each(parseData, function (i, v) {
                    debugger;
                    for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
                        optionCity = $('<option></option>').text(v[i]['CITY']);  
                        optionState = v[i]['STATE']; 
                         ddlCity.append(optionCity);
                         txtState.val(optionState);
                    }                                  
                });